# Jquery Accordion - use anchors to open & go to specific section

Tags: jquery, anchor, accordion

Since jQueryUI 1.10 "activate" method has been removed and I had some issue opening links to my accordion sections.

That's why I looked for a solution to my problem that I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15339847/jquery-accordion-use-anchors-to-open-specific-panels-from-external-and-interna/15342809#15342809).

But I still have a remaining problem.

I would like the link to open specific tab but **also scroll down to it**.
I tried to add some id to paragraphs without success as you can see on http://jsfiddle.net/VZ3T5/232/

Any help would be highly appreciated.

HTML:

```
    <a class="opener" data-panel="0" href="#question1">Open & go to Question 1</a>

<a class="opener" data-panel="1" href="#question2">Open & go to Question 2</a>

<a class="opener" data-panel="2" href="#question3">Open & go to Question 3</a>

<a class="opener" data-panel="3" href="#question4">Open & go to Question 4</a>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div id="accordion">

<h3>Question 1</h3>

    <div>
        <p>Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer
            ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit
            amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo
            ut odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.</p>
    </div>

<h3>Question 2</h3>

    <div>
        <p id="question2">Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet
            purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttitor
            velit, faucibus interdum tellus libero ac justo. Vivamus non quam. In suscipit
            faucibus urna.</p>
    </div>

<h3>Question 3</h3>

    <div>
        <p id="question3">Nam enim risus, molestie et, porta ac, aliquam ac, risus. Quisque lobortis.
            Phasellus pellentesque purus in massa. Aenean in pede. Phasellus ac libero
            ac tellus pellentesque semper. Sed ac felis. Sed commodo, magna quis lacinia
            ornare, quam ante aliquam nisi, eu iaculis leo purus venenatis dui.</p>
        <ul>
            <li>List item one</li>
            <li>List item two</li>
            <li>List item three</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

<h3>Question 4</h3>

    <div>
        <p id="question4">Cras dictum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et
            malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus
            orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aenean lacinia mauris vel
            est.</p>
        <p>Suspendisse eu nisl. Nullam ut libero. Integer dignissim consequat lectus.
            Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per
            inceptos himenaeos.</p>
    </div>
    </div>
```

jQuery:

```
 var $accordion = $("#accordion");

$accordion.accordion({
      collapsible: true, active: false
    });

$(".opener").on("click", function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        toOpen = $this.data("panel");

    $accordion.accordion("option", "active", toOpen);

    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var $accordion = $("#accordion");

$accordion.accordion({
    collapsible: true,
    active: false
});

$(".opener").on("click", function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        toOpen = $this.data("panel");
    $accordion.accordion("option", "active", toOpen);
    var timer = $accordion.accordion("option", "animate");//get animate value
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("html,body").animate({
            scrollTop: $($("#accordion>div").get(toOpen)).offset().top
        }, 300);
    }, timer); //Use it in the timer.
    return false;
});
```

The simple method will be to put a timer till the accordion is opened. Accordion has an option of specifying the animate value and that can also be used as a timer

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GCu2D/1493/

Comment: Yes! That was it. I didn't think about timer. Thanks a lot for your fast answer ;-)